# Is there a way to map the gradient fill to another variable in a ridgeline plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'd like to map different variables for the x axis, y-axis, height of the ridges and gradient fill of the plot along the y-axis.

How can I reconfigure the below code such that the "fill" works with a different variable than that specified by x?

```
# Example for `geom_density_ridges_gradient()`
ggplot(lincoln_weather, aes(x = `Mean Temperature [F]`, y = `Month`, fill = stat(x))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = 3, rel_min_height = 0.01) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Temp. [F]", option = "C") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  labs(title = 'Temperatures in Lincoln NE in 2016') +
  theme_ridges(font_size = 13, grid = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(Lincoln_weather)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: I actually dont have the above dataset, I'm adapting the above code to work with a similar dataset and have had trouble getting it to work. I've instead provided a sample dataset linked here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NRnSvjnYD8Clto1F9ydqiMuOllWNN8ZbNvNrkgKSijA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The goal is to use x = Scan Number, y = Location, height = Volume and SUVmax as the gradient for each scan # timepoint. Each location can have multiple observations (i.e. volume and SUVmax) at different timepoints (Scan number).